# Rails request.ip or request.remote_ip return different value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I store IP of client using req.ip and req.remote_ip then it showing different result when request twice using same device and internet connection.

for first req it returns:-

```
2402:8100:3092:16f4:1:1:cd28:307f
```

for second request it returns

```
27.97.134.92
```

which is ipv4.

Is there any way to get either only ipv6 or only ipv4 address?

Comment: Can you confirm your client is using Proxy?

Comment: actually I am using ngrok tunnel where my server connected to wifi and I am using mobile data with mobile